# Can you customize the Change Password hosted UI screen shown in Amplify?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to add some text to the bottom of the Change Password UI form within an Amplify app, but there doesn't seem to be an option to customize this form.

Is this possible?

My use-case is that I want to write out the password format required (such as number of characters, numbers etc) - I can do it on Forgot Password but not on Change Password that is shown after a user enters their temporary credentials after having been added to the Cognito user pool.

The customization information page I am using is this one [Amplify Authenticator Customization](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/customization)

The Amplify Change Password form itself is as follows:

[image]

I can add some text to *every* hosted UI form using the code:

```
const components = {
    Footer() {
      return (
             <View textAlign="center" padding="5px">
                 <div>
                    All passwords must be 8 characters or more and have at 
                    least 1 number, 1 special character, 1 uppercase &amp; 1 lowercase.
                 </div>
             </View>
         );
     },
};
 
const withAuthenticatorOptions = {
     hideSignUp: true,
     components: components,
}

export default withAuthenticator(MyApp, withAuthenticatorOptions);
```

but I'd rather not show it on the initial Login screen as it looks rubbish and also gives hints to every bad actor as to what the password requirements are.